# error in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

In the query below, i get an error on the 'LettingPercent' on the fourth line, 'invalid column name'. I want to use each result returned in the lettingpercentage to calculate a letting fee which is on the fourth line of my statement

```
declare @let varchar(50)
select 
CONVERT(varchar(50), InstructionLettingFee.percentage)+'%' as 'LettingPercent',
CONVERT(decimal(18,2), LettingPercent / (100 * DealFees.pddrl_TermRent)) as LettingFee
from tableOne
left outer join tableTwo LettingInstruction on LettingInstruction.ColumnOne=     tableOne.ColumnOne
left outer join TableThree InstructionLettingFee on InstructionLettingFee.ColumnForOne = LettingInstruction.ColumTwo
left outer join TableFour DealFees on DealFees.ColumnOne = pDeal.ColumnOne
```

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes are unnecessary.  But the problem is that you are referring to the value in the next line.  Instead go back to the original data:

```
declare @let varchar(50)
select CONVERT(varchar(50), InstructionLettingFee.percentage)+'%') as LettingPercent,
       CONVERT(decimal(18,2), InstructionLettingFee.percentage / (100 * DealFees.pddrl_TermRent)) as LettingFee
from tableOne
left outer join tableTwo LettingInstruction on LettingInstruction.ColumnOne=     tableOne.ColumnOne
left outer join TableThree InstructionLettingFee on InstructionLettingFee.ColumnForOne = LettingInstruction.ColumTwo
left outer join TableFour DealFees on DealFees.ColumnOne = pDeal.ColumnOne;
```

EDIT:

To prevent divide-by-0, put the `case` around the calculation:

```
       (case when DealFees.pddrl_TermRent > 0
             then CONVERT(decimal(18,2), InstructionLettingFee.percentage / (100 * DealFees.pddrl_TermRent))
        end) as LettingFee
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i think your solution is the closest. One more question though, What if i wanted to add a case to the second convert statement, checking if the percentage is greater than 0 before doing the division as you cant divide by zero. At the moment i just get a flash of result then and error saying cant divide by zero.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an alias like that, you will need to repeat the statement.
Even if you could you have turned `LettingPercent` into a string.
Try:

```
    declare @let varchar(50)
    select 
    CONVERT(varchar(50), InstructionLettingFee.percentage)+'%' as 'LettingPercent',
LettingFee =
case InstructionLettingFee.percentage
when 0 then cast( 0 as decimal(18,2) )
else  CONVERT(decimal(18,2), InstructionLettingFee.percentage / (100 * DealFees.pddrl_TermRent)) 
end
    from tableOne
    left outer join tableTwo LettingInstruction on LettingInstruction.ColumnOne=     tableOne.ColumnOne
    left outer join TableThree InstructionLettingFee on InstructionLettingFee.ColumnForOne = LettingInstruction.ColumTwo
    left outer join TableFour DealFees on DealFees.ColumnOne = pDeal.ColumnOne
```

Comment: This part of the query is having incorrect syntax: +'%' as 'LettingPercent'

Comment: hi jenson, can you help with the case statement ? im still getting a cannot divide by zero. Thank you

Comment: @ife, try that please

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an alias in the query which is wrong, please try the following query:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(50), LettingPercent)+'% LettingPercent',
CONVERT(decimal(18,2), LettingPercent / (100 * pddrl_TermRent)) as LettingFee
from
(select 
InstructionLettingFee.percentage as LettingPercent,
DealFees.pddrl_TermRent
from tableOne
left outer join tableTwo LettingInstruction on LettingInstruction.ColumnOne=     tableOne.ColumnOne
left outer join TableThree InstructionLettingFee on InstructionLettingFee.ColumnForOne = LettingInstruction.ColumTwo
left outer join TableFour DealFees on DealFees.ColumnOne = pDeal.ColumnOne)
```

Comment: LettingPercent is a varchar(50) then u divide by it in your unecessary outer query

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, columns dynamically created cannot be accessed by other columns at the same level.

You can use a derived table to achieve this though:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(50), LettingPercent)+ '%' as LettingPercent,
    CONVERT(decimal(18,2), LettingPercent / (100 * TermRent)) as LettingFee
FROM (
    SELECT 
        InstructionLettingFee.percentage AS LettingPercent,
        DealFees.pddrl_TermRent AS TermRent
    from tableOne
    left outer join tableTwo LettingInstruction on LettingInstruction.ColumnOne = tableOne.ColumnOne
    left outer join TableThree InstructionLettingFee on InstructionLettingFee.ColumnForOne = LettingInstruction.ColumTwo
    left outer join TableFour DealFees on DealFees.ColumnOne = pDeal.ColumnOne
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the AS keyword and not having any spaces in your alises, there is no need for quoting the string. But if you want to add quoting to your aliases then you should use double quote, and not single quotes, i.e.

... AS "LettingPercent"

Comment: Actually no! The ANSI standards states to use double quotes. If you are using old database such as Sybase the preferred is single quotes. In some database implementations single quote may work, but is not preferred. You can also use [] for alias names, but again ANSI standards states double quotes and is the safest way.

Comment: I suggest you read my answer and comment once again. Not all versions of sql server support single quotes.

Comment: I am not sure what user "jenson-button-event" is trying to do, by adding incorrect comments in a rude way and then removing them. Also it is quite useless to edit an answer by adding a space at the end of a line. Is this some kind of spamming game?

Comment: i edited it as that was the only way i could remove the downvote. and removed my erroneus comments